# Liferay webcontent vote boolean yes or no

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a webcontent in liferay, I want add boolean check to web content YES or NO and in the admin would like to see total count of Yes and No. Please advise is it available in liferay OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

There is "out of the box" for such a requirement. You could add a polls portlet right next to your webcontent display portlet.

Please check this "Knowledge Base" article about it:
https://dev.liferay.com/es/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/find-out-what-others-think-or-do-using-polls

The poll is not directly bound to a webcontent (or rendered inside), but you could archive your goal withit.